# Tensor product of regular modules is regular

Tags: representation-theory, tensor-products, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ and $H$ two algebraic linear groups, $V$ a regular $G$- module and $W$ a regular $H$ - module. I want to prove that $V \otimes W$ is a regular $G \times H$-module. If $V$ and $W$ are regular modules, it means that there exist $\phi : G \times V \to GL(V)$, with $\phi(g, v)= \phi(g)v$ and $\psi : H \times W \to GL(W)$, with $\psi(h, w) = \phi(h)w$ and with $\psi$ and $\phi$ are both regular. That means that they are both polynomials in certain variables (the entries of a matrix $x_{ii}$ and $\frac{1}{det(x)}$). So we can define $\omega : (G \times H) \times (V \otimes W) \to GL(V \otimes W)$ such that $\omega((g, h), (v, w)) = \phi(g)\psi(h)(v \otimes w)$, which is again regular because the product of polynomials is a polynomial. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}$As far as I understand and remember, you are in the following situation: there are polynomial maps $P,Q$
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbb{A}^m & \overset P\to & \mathbb{A}^n\\
\cup && \cup \\
G &\underset{\phi}\to & \text{GL}(V)
\end{array}
$$
and
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbb{A}^r & \overset Q\to & \mathbb{A}^s\\
\cup && \cup \\
H &\underset{\phi}\to& \text{GL}(W)
\end{array}
$$ where the integers $m,n,r,s\ge 1$ are determined by the dimensions of $G,H,V,W$; now, the tensor representation $\phi\otimes\psi : G\times H \to \text{GL}(V\otimes W)$ is defined as $(g,h)\mapsto \phi(g)\otimes\psi(h)$, which is the unique automorphism $V\otimes W \to V\otimes W$ induced by the bilinear map $V\times W \to V\otimes W : (v,w)\mapsto \phi g(v)\otimes \psi h(w)$ using the universal property of $V\otimes W$:
$$
\begin{CD}
V\times W @>(\phi g,\psi h)>> V\otimes W \\ 
@VVV @| \\
V\otimes W @>>\phi g\otimes\psi h> V\otimes W
\end{CD}
$$
The endomorphism $\phi g\otimes \psi h$ now can be concretely expressed as the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) of the two matrices $\phi g, \psi h$.

Regularity (say, for $\phi$) should amount to the request that each $\phi(g)$ can be written as a $d\times d$ matrix ($d = \dim V$) whose entries are polynomials in $k[T_1,\dots,T_m,\frac{1}{\det}]$ ($k$ the field where you take the varieties).

Similarly, $\psi(h)$ is a polinomial in $k[Y_1,\dots,Y_r,\frac{1}{\det}]$; from this, it follows that $\phi(g)\otimes\psi(h)$, i.e. the matrix obtained as Kronecker product of two matrices whose entries are polynomials, is again a polynomial; *furtim*, you are exploiting the natural isomorphism $k[E]\otimes k[F]\cong k[E\sqcup F]$, valid for sets $E,F$.

This can be proved directly, or deduced from the fact that $k[\_]$ is the free $k$-algebra functor ${\sf Set} \to {\sf Alg}_k$, and as such it sends coproducts (of sets, i.e. disjoint unions) into coproducts of $k$-algebras ($k$-bilinear tensor products).

It is this last remark that allows you to say that an abstract tensor $\phi g\otimes \psi h$, i.e. an element of $k[T_1,\dots,T_m,\frac{1}{\det}]\otimes k[Y_1,\dots,Y_r,\frac{1}{\det'}]$ "is" a polynomial: it's canonically identified to a polynomial in $k[T_1,\dots,T_m,\frac{1}{\det}, Y_1,\dots,Y_r,\frac{1}{\det'}]$.